# Dual Interface Network Card Issue on 2nd NIC

Tags: networking, centos, nic

I'm working on reconfiguring an existing production server and having trouble with a dual port Intel PCIe card. It's running CentOS 6.4 [*2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64*] and it seems like it's a driver issue on the 2nd NIC as it's detected by the system.

There was a bond interface that I believe at some point both these Intel NICs have been members of *(I say this due to some of the comments in the old interface config files)*. That being said, when I came to reconfigure the network, only eth0 was a member of the bond and eth1 is/was nowhere to be seen. I've since removed the bond interface.

Here's what I've done so far;

- NetworkManager isn't running, just using the CentOS network service
- Both Interfaces are listed with lspci
- Deleted the 70-persistent-net.rules file and rebooted
- Manually modifying 70-persistent-net.rules with the MAC ADDR of eth1

Here is some more output showing why I think it's a driver issue, though I'm struggling to resolve that.

```
# lspci|grep -i net
  03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
  03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
  03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
  03:00.3 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
  04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
  04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599EB 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
```

04:00.1 is the culprit

```
# find /sys|grep drivers.*04:00
  /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbe/0000:04:00.0
```

I figure it's a driver issue due to 0000:04:00.1 not being listed with the above.

```
# ifconfig -a
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:E2:BA:17:XX:XX  
            inet6 addr: fe80::XXX/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:19695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:1999668 (1.9 MiB)  TX bytes:9176 (8.9 KiB)

  eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D8:9D:67:32:XX:XX  
            UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

  eth3      ...
  eth4      ...
  eth5      ...
  lo        ...
```

Any assistance is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're several years behind on updates. Install them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've done a yum update, now running CentOS 6.10. Still the same issue. I'm going to try booting into a livecd when I get a chance. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Just booted into a Linux Mint 18 LiveCD and it too only detects one of the interfaces. Oddly I can see light coming from the SFP+ module, and when hooking up a fibre cable the lights at the rear show activity. Does anyone have any ideas? I might try updating the BIOS now - it's an HP DL360 G8.

Comment: Check `dmesg` to see if any problems were noted when bringing up the interface. Now it sounds likely that you have a defective NIC.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for the suggestion, that pointed me to the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This was caused by having an unsupported SFP module installed in the second port.**

Thanks to Michael Hampton's suggestion of checking `dmesg` I was able to find this line;

```
ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: failed to load because an unsupported SFP+ or QSFP module type was detected.
ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: Reload the driver after installing a supported module.
ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: PCI INT B disabled
```

After installing a supported transceiver and rebooting, the interface then came up as expected as eth1.